# how to shut of the buffer of a BA6110 OTA?

Tags: ota

[image]

What would the best way to shut off a BA6110 OTA buffer?

- Tie pin 7 high (+15V)
- Tie pin 7 low (-15V)
- Tie pin 8 buffer out back into pin 7 (which I believe is wrong, I tried that before and might have caused the BA6110 to get hot). It is the correct way to shut down a LM13700 buffer, but this is Darlington based.

Here the output pin (8) is high albeit having R5, binding it to pin 7 would open Q17 and via Q18 it would tie to -15V, causing current to flow.

Comment: The buffer is non inverting. That should tell you what to do.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 if the BA6110 is equal to to the BA662 (witch it is not), the BA6110 has linearizing diodes and the BA662 not, it should be tied high, http://atosynth.blogspot.com/2017/07/ba662-pinout.html contains image to disable buffer. that's why I'm asking.

Comment: If output is high, resistor 0 drop indicates no power, so yes input high = output high = off

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thank you very much. so i tie the input high and leave the output floating. as Roland does in their Jupiter synth's.